# CSS hover table cell

Tags: html, css, hover

I got a table and I would like to have different text boxes when hovering on cells.

```html
<div class="plan">
     <h2 class="title">Premium</h2>
     <div align="center">
       <p class="plan-price">499<span>&euro;</span></p>
     </div>
       <ul class="plan-features">
         <li><strong>Hello1</strong></li>
         <li><strong>Hello2</strong></li>
         <li><strong>Hello3</strong>></li>
         <li><strong>Hello4</strong></li>
         <li><strong>Hello5</strong></li>
       </ul>
       <a href="#" class="plan-button">Start Now</a>
</div>
```

I would like to show a box with some text when for example a user move the pointer over Hello1.

This is the css code

```css
.plan-features {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            line-height: 2;
            font-size: 12px;
            color: #999;
            text-align: center;
          }

          .plan-features > li > strong {
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #888;
          }
   
   .box:hover{
     text-align: center;
     color: white;
     width: 200px;
     margin: 10px -12px;
     height: 100px;
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.8);
   }
```

I tried to add this to the first `<li>` tag

```html
<ul class="plan-features">
                    <div class="box"><li><strong>Hello1</strong></li></div>
```

but obviously the box is shown with the text "Hello1", how can i hide "hello1" and add some other text?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this! i tried to implement according to your requirements. But do explain what are you trying to achieve from this. Should there be different text for each `li` element? There are other ways too. Which would be simpler than this

**HTML**

```
 <div>
 <strong class="overlap hoverOn">Hello1</strong>
 <strong class="overlap hide">someText</strong>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
div
{
  position:relative;
}
.overlap
{
  position:absolute;
  top:0; left:0;
}
.hide { 
    display: none;
    background: red;
}

.hoverOn:hover + .hide {
    display: block;
}
```

[JSfiddle Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/4a4xt18f/)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

**HTML**

```
<li><strong hover-text="Some text1">Hello1</strong></li>
```

**CSS**

```
strong:hover {
  font-size: 0;
}
strong:hover:before {
  font-size: 12px;
  content: attr(hover-text);
}
```

Full code here: https://jsfiddle.net/5qkruhuc/

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this

**HTML Code:**

```
            <div class="plan">
            <h2 class="title">Premium</h2>
            <div align="center">
                <p class="plan-price">499<span>&euro;</span></p>
            </div>
            <ul class="plan-features">
                <li><strong>Hello1</strong></li>
                <li><strong>Hello2</strong></li>
                <li><strong>Hello3</strong>></li>
                <li><strong>Hello4</strong></li>
                <li><strong>Hello5</strong></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" class="plan-button">Start Now</a>
        </div>
```

**CSS Code :**

```
                .plan-features {
                margin-bottom: 20px;
                line-height: 2;
                font-size: 12px;
                color: #999;
                text-align: center;
            }

                .plan-features li strong:hover {
                    text-align: center;
                    color: white;
                    width: 200px;
                    margin: 10px -12px;
                    height: 100px;
                    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.8);
                }
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/rajnikpatel/e7rrk9xy/

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution using JavaScript, but the `<div id="mynav" class="box">` is always shown except when I click on "x". Instead I want that the box is shown only when I click on "Hello1" and closed after have clicked on the "x"

Here's the code

```js
JavaScript:

<script>
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
}
</script>
```

```css
CSS:

.plan-features {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            line-height: 2;
            font-size: 12px;
            color: #999;
            text-align: center;
          }

          .plan-features > li > strong {
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #888;
          }
   
   
   .box{
     text-align: center;
     color: white;
     width: 200px;
     margin: 10px -20px;
     height: 100px;
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.8);
     overflow-x: hidden;
            transition: 0.5s;
   }
   
   .closeButton {
     color: yellow; 
     top: 20px;
            right: 45px; 
   }
```

```html
HTML:

<ul class="plan-features">
 <div id="myNav" class="box">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebutton" onclick="closeNav()">x</a>
        <br />Some Text
 </div> 
    <li onclick="openNav()"><strong>Hello1</strong></li> 
    <li><strong>Hello2</strong></li>
    <li><strong>Hello3</strong></li>
    <li><strong>Hello4</strong></li>
    <li><strong>Hello5</strong></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is not answer, it's new question. Please delete this answer and update your original question with new issues you have